# How to change the size of the browse window by using button?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am struck in the case of changing the size of the browse window by using button. Could you please help me by sharing some sample query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HEIGHT-PIXELS` and `WIDTH-PIXELS` properties control the size of the browse widget. You can change them in a button's `ON CHOOSE` event:

```
ON CHOOSE OF btnIncreaseHeight IN FRAME fFrame /* Increase Height */
DO:
    Browse-1:HEIGHT-PIXELS = Browse-1:HEIGHT-PIXELS + 5.
END.
```

You can make similar events for decreasing the height and for increasing/decreasing the width.